# How can I update the design of my panel in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem updating my design in my panel. I have a big panel, which I want to include smaller ones. I have a comboBox and i choose how many panels I want to have and update the number of small panels in the big one every time I change the index in the comboBox.

This is the code for the listener

```
class listenerComboBox implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selectedIndex = simulationFrame.getServersNumberComboBox().getSelectedIndex();
            arrangeCenterPanels(simulationFrame.getjCenter(), simulationFrame.getPanelQ1(), simulationFrame.getPanelQ2(), simulationFrame.getPanelQ3(), simulationFrame.getPanelQ4(), simulationFrame.getPanelQ5(), selectedIndex+1);
        }
    }
```

and this is the code for the design

```
public static void arrangeCenterPanels(JPanel jCenter, JPanel Q1, JPanel Q2, JPanel Q3, JPanel Q4, JPanel Q5, int serversNumber)
    {
        if (serversNumber == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(serversNumber);
            jCenter.removeAll();

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.insets = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 10);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c.gridx = 0;
            jCenter.add(Q1, c);

            jCenter.updateUI();
        }
        if (serversNumber == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(serversNumber);
            jCenter.removeAll();

            GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
            c2.gridy = 0;
            c2.insets = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 10);
            c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c2.gridx = 0;
            jCenter.add(Q1, c2);
            c2.gridx = 1;
            jCenter.add(Q2, c2);
            jCenter.updateUI();

        }
        if (serversNumber == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(serversNumber);
            jCenter.removeAll();

            GridBagConstraints c3 = new GridBagConstraints();
            c3.gridy = 0;
            c3.insets = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 10);
            c3.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c3.gridx = 0;
            jCenter.add(Q1, c3);
            c3.gridx = 1;
            jCenter.add(Q2, c3);
            c3.gridx = 2;
            jCenter.add(Q3, c3);

            jCenter.updateUI();

        }
        if (serversNumber == 4)
        {
            System.out.println(serversNumber);
            jCenter.removeAll();

            GridBagConstraints c4 = new GridBagConstraints();
            c4.gridy = 0;
            c4.insets = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 10);
            c4.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c4.gridx = 0;
            jCenter.add(Q1, c4);
            c4.gridx = 1;
            jCenter.add(Q2, c4);
            c4.gridx = 2;
            jCenter.add(Q3, c4);
            c4.gridx = 3;
            jCenter.add(Q4, c4);

            jCenter.updateUI();

        }
        if (serversNumber == 5)
        {
            System.out.println(serversNumber);

            jCenter.removeAll();
            GridBagConstraints c5 = new GridBagConstraints();

            Q1.repaint();
            c5.gridy = 0;
            c5.insets = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 10);
            c5.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c5.gridx = 0;
            jCenter.add(Q1, c5);
            c5.gridx = 1;
            jCenter.add(Q2, c5);
            c5.gridx = 2;
            jCenter.add(Q3, c5);
            c5.gridx = 3;
            jCenter.add(Q4, c5);
            c5.gridx = 4;
            jCenter.add(Q5, c5);

            jCenter.updateUI();

        }
```

I have a bigger class, where I design the entire frame, and there all i did was to declare the panels. For now, that code does nothing, nothing is showing up.

Comment: Do Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, and Q5 have anything in them?  Also, GridBagConstraints.CENTER is not a valid fill value.  Did you mean to set anchor instead?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted wasn't a complete runnable example, so I had to make some assumptions.

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: One server]

Here's the GUI after I selected 3.

[image: Three servers]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I used a `FlowLayout` for the main `JPanel`, since it appeared from your code that you wanted a horizontal layout.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MultiPanelExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MultiPanelExample());

    }

    private int numberOfServers;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public MultiPanelExample() {
        this.numberOfServers = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("MultiPanel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createComboBoxPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createComboBoxPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Integer[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        JComboBox<Integer> serverComboBox = new JComboBox<>(values);
        serverComboBox.addActionListener(event -> {
            this.numberOfServers = (Integer) serverComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            frame.remove(mainPanel);
            mainPanel = createMainPanel();
            frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        });
        panel.add(serverComboBox);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfServers; index++) {
            panel.add(createServerPanel(index + 1));
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createServerPanel(int number) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 3));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Server " + number);
        panel.add(label);

        return panel;
    }

}
```